# SQL if statement syntax error

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I've been trying to write this simple mysql statement to check if a table exists:

```
IF object_id('carpool'.'users', 'U') is not null THEN
    PRINT 'Present!'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not accounted for'
END IF
```

'carpool' is my schema and 'users' is a table
My sql version is 5.1.52-community
I keep getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF' at line 1   0.000 sec
```

I've tried several syntaxes such as IF BEGIN END ELSE BEGIN END to no avail.
any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this in a simple query or a stored proc ?

Comment: it's a simple query. ; gives the same error

Comment: You can't use `IF...ELSE...END IF` in a simple query, you have to create a stored proc if you want to use this. But for your problem, there are simplier solutions.

Comment: or use `SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`, or even `SELECT IF(..., ..., ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a form of T-SQL, which MySQL does not support.

There is no print function, nor object_id. There is a form of IF function that can be used in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT IF(1 = 1, 'present', 'not');
```

Are you reading MSSQL doco instead of MySQL doco? MSSQL supports these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are after, you might want to use something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM information_schema.tables 
                    WHERE table_schema = 'carpool' AND table_name = 'users')
       THEN 'Present'
       ELSE 'Not accounted for' END;
```

This will check if table `users` exists in `carpool` schema. Please see example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/142b34/1).

Comment: Ok that doesn't answer my question but it does help with what i wanted to do. I will use ur code thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Every statement must be terminated by semicolon.

Like this

```
IF object_id('carpool'.'users', 'U') is not null THEN
   PRINT 'Present!';
ELSE
   PRINT 'Not accounted for';
END IF;
```

Comment: Right, but if he executes a simple query, it will not work anyway